# google map doesnt not work on IE

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a google map to show on a page, it works all fine on other browsers except IE 8 not sure for the above verzions of IE..

The thing is that most of the users uses IE and I want to solve it out why this is not working on IE?

```
$table = "";
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $table .= "<table border = \"1\" width=\"800px\">  

                    <tr><td style = \"background:#EEEEEE;\"><b>Arka</b></td>   <td align=\"left\" width= \"220px\" style = \"background:#EEEEEE;\">{$row['arka']}</td> <td width = \"480px\" rowspan = \"4\"> <div style = \"width:480px; height:230px;\" id= \"div-{$row['id']}\">Map here</div></td> </tr>
            <tr><td><b>Orari</b></td>  <td align=\"left\">{$row['orari']}</td></tr>  
            <tr><td><b>Pauza</b> </td>  <td align=\"left\">{$row['pauza']}</td></tr>  
            <tr><td><b>Shtune</b></td> <td align=\"left\">{$row['shtune']}</td></tr>  
            </table> <br>";

            echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">loadMap("'.$row['adresa'].'",'.$row['id'].');</script>';

            }
            echo $table;
                ?>
```

end here is the function which load the map:

```
function loadMap(street,div_id) {


$.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+street+",Prishtina&sensor=true", 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { 

            $.each(data, function() {
                $.each(this, function(key, value) {
                    switch (key) {

                        case "lat":

                        alert(value) // access to this node works fine                      
                        break;

                        case "lng":

                        alert(value) // access to this node works fine                      
                        break;

                        default: 
                        //window.alert(divid);

                        var myCenter=new 
           google.maps.LatLng(value.geometry.location.lat,value.geometry.location.lng);
                        var mapProp = {
                            center: myCenter,
                            zoom:17,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                        };

                        var map = new           
                            google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("div-" +  
                            div_id),mapProp);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: myCenter,
                            title:'Click to zoom',
                            //icon: 'img/logo3.png'


                        });

                        marker.setMap(map);

        // Zoom to 9 when clicking on marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
            map.setZoom(9);
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        });

        break;
           }       
               });
                   });
                   }
                   });
```

Comment: We had the same problem - didn't have time to find out why IE was failing - so recommended users used a different browser.

Comment: this is ridiculous... there should be a solution for this too...

Comment: have you included http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/ it should solve the issue you are describing.

Comment: where should I add canvas tag???

Comment: it is a .js file so you include it in the header, normally with the only if less than IE8 tag. <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Path/to/excanvas.min.js"></script>  with the <![if !IE]>
<script src="your-non-IE-script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]>

Comment: added as answer to clarify, thanks.

Comment: Google maps will work in IE8.

Comment: have you checked your console?  I used google maps which is working in IE8.

Comment: how did you use ?? can u be more specific??? as per my case is not working... have u done any extra job for IE or it just worked for all at once??

Comment: Have you checked it?  Try developers tools F12 to get the console and share it.

Answer (score 1):

To use anything that is **Canvas** based (almost all Google objects are).  You'll want to **include [excanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/)**.

Simply add the following in your `head` tag in your HTML.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Path/to/excanvas.min.js"></script>
```

For it to only **load in IE** do the following:

```
<![if !IE]>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Path/to/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<![endif]>
```

Comment: I added these inside header and dowloaded the library ... and still not working :S

Comment: I dont know why sublime makes as highlighted syntax on <![if !IE]> and <![endif]> is it somthing wrong with that?

Comment: nope but most IDE's don't recognize it.  Also do you have a jsfiddle of this?